# Rails 4.x - Bypass decompression and/or parsing of gzip json POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, gzip

I'm trying to POST a 10-20MB gzipped JSON object to a rails controller/action. How would one go about just bypassing parsing altogether? All I need to do is write it to the filesystem, in its original format, able to be gunzipped at a later time.

I've seen one example that attempts decompress then parse it -- http://arnab.ch/blog/2012/09/android-how-to-send-gzipped-json-in-http-request/

While attempting to use that as a starting point, POST-ing a gzipped json file, it says that the file is not in gzip format.

```
echo '{"name":"test"}'|gzip >> test.json.gz

curl -X POST -H 'Content-Encoding: gzip' -d @test.json.gz -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://server.com/endpoint

lib::GzipFile::Error (not in gzip format):
  lib/middleware/compressed_requests.rb:31:in 'initialize'
  lib/middleware/compressed_requests.rb:31:in 'new'
  lib/middleware/compressed_requests.rb:31:in 'decode'
  lib/middleware/compressed_requests.rb:18:in 'call'


  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-railsexpress/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-railsexpress/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-railsexpress/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (14.5ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-railsexpress/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (49.7ms)
```

If I don't add that middleware it throws an error about not being able to parse the request with a json lexical error.

```
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (lexical error: invalid char in json text.)-�S�V�K�MU�R*I-.Q����@Z
```

Any insight or alternate methods would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this sorted out by monkey patching the ParamsParser class. Not very elegant, but does the trick.

```
module ActionDispatch
  class ParamsParser
    class ParseError < StandardError
      attr_reader :original_exception

      def initialize(message, original_exception)
        super(message)
        @original_exception = original_exception
      end
    end

    DEFAULT_PARSERS = {Mime::JSON => :json}

    def initialize(app, parsers = {})
      @app, @parsers = app, DEFAULT_PARSERS.merge(parsers)
    end

    def call(env)
      if params = parse_formatted_parameters(env)
        env["action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"] = params
      end

      @app.call(env)
    end

    private
    def parse_formatted_parameters(env)
      request = Request.new(env)

      return false if request.content_length.zero?

      strategy = @parsers[request.content_mime_type]

      return false unless strategy

      case strategy
        when Proc
          strategy.call(request.raw_post)
        when :json
           ## BEGIN CUSTOM HANDLER FOR GZIP ENCODED JSON
           if !['gzip'].include? env['HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING']
            data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.raw_post)
          else
            data = request.raw_post
          end
          ## END CUSTOM HANDLER FOR GZIP ENCODED JSON
          data = {:_json => data} unless data.is_a?(Hash)
          Request::Utils.deep_munge(data).with_indifferent_access
        else
          false
      end
    rescue Exception => e # JSON or Ruby code block errors
      logger(env).debug "Error occurred while parsing request parameters.\nContents:\n\n#{request.raw_post}"

      raise ParseError.new(e.message, e)
    end

    def logger(env)
      env['action_dispatch.logger'] || ActiveSupport::Logger.new($stderr)
    end
  end
end
```